# Unbuffered character input for python on a windows machine

Tags: python, input, character

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to design a stopwatch with lap timing. When you press "L" then a lap is completed and when you press "S" all laps are completed and the timings are displayed in order.

While in C++ I can do this with the function _getch() from conio.h and it would be quite easy. I want to write this program in python as it would be a lot more easier and also the time handling in C++ proved to be hard.

Still I did write a program (which was for cube timing) on this link:
 [Cube timer](http://cubetimersoftware.blogspot.com)

**Problem**

There is no function like _getch(). And this is a problem because at the end of a lap you can't press a key and an enter key because it would be time taking and irritating for the user.

**things I read**

I read about the curses library but alas it has no windows port.

I tried a program that was supposed to work according to the website. This was from the link

[Link to getch recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892-getch-like-unbuffered-character-reading-from-stdin/)

But it did not work.

**What I tried:**

1. `msvcrt.getch()`

```
    >>> import msvcrt
    >>> msvcrt.getch()
    '\xff'
```

I believe that FF is the hexadecimal equivalent of 255.

I did not understand why this is happenning.

1. `readch()`  as sugggested in @martineau

   import msvcrt

   def readch(echo=True):
       "Get a single character on Windows."
       while msvcrt.kbhit():  # clear out keyboard buffer
           msvcrt.getch()
       ch = msvcrt.getch()
       while ch in '\x00\xe0':  # arrow or function key prefix?
           msvcrt.getch()
           ch = msvcrt.getch()  # second call returns the actual key code
       if echo:
           msvcrt.putch(ch)
       return ch.decode()

   a = []

   for i in range(10):
       a.append(readch())

The error that i got:

```
>>> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python25/1.py", line 30, in <module>
    a.append(readch())
  File "C:/Python25/1.py", line 25, in readch
    return ch.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**What I need help with**

A function that works like _getch() or something equivalent that works on a windows machine.

**Machine specs**

Python IDLE 2.5.4 or 2.6 or 2.7

Windows XP SP3

Comment: Can you show us  your Python code and how you're using it?

Comment: I am sorry. I am on a mobile device.

Comment: it's hard to help if you don't post actual code

Comment: Okay sir. I will post the code as soon as I login on a machine.

Comment: have you tried `import sys` and instead of getchar `sys.stdin.read(1)` ?

Comment: Yes. I have tried it.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've used that seems to work in a Windows console. It's somewhat similar to that ActiveState recipe except that it only works on Windows. It's based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) **msdn** documentation for `_getwch()`.

```
#### windows only ####
import msvcrt

def readch(echo=True):
    "Get a single character on Windows."
    while msvcrt.kbhit():  # clear out keyboard buffer
        msvcrt.getwch()
    ch = msvcrt.getwch()
    if ch in u'\x00\xe0':  # arrow or function key prefix?
        ch = msvcrt.getwch()  # second call returns the actual key code
    if echo:
        msvcrt.putwch(ch)
    return ch

def pause(prompt='Press any key to continue . . .'):
    if prompt:
        print prompt,
    readch(echo=False)
```

(Updated to handle Unicode).

Comment: In 2.6+ you can use `getwch`/`putwch` if you want Unicode. Since you're using a `b''` literal, I assume you don't need 2.5 support.

Comment: @eryksun: [`_getwch()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) returns a `wint_t`, which I am unsure of how to translate into a Python Unicode string after reading [When to use getwch() instead of getch() in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516708/when-to-use-getwch-instead-of-getch-in-windows).

Comment: It's already done for you in `msvcrt`, see [PC/msvcrtmodule.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/PC/msvcrtmodule.c#l209). A `wint_t` is any type that can represent a `wchar_t`, which is what Python uses for Unicode on Windows in versions prior to 3.3.

Comment: Since the default for `decode` in 2.x is ASCII, using `getwch` means you don't have to worry about the current code page. Win32 handles that for you.

Comment: @eryksun: Yes, I see now that the docs say [`msvcrt.getwch()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html?highlight=getwch#msvcrt.getwch) returns a Unicode value -- so using it instead of `getch`()` in my answer ought to work and make it support Unicode (for Python 2.6+).

Comment: 3.3 had to switch to explicitly using `wchar_t` and `PyUnicode_FromOrdinal(ch)`: [3.3 PC/msvcrtmodule.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/bd8afb90ebf2/PC/msvcrtmodule.c#l213).

Comment: @eryksun: Do you know if 3.3 is being built with `_WCONIO_DEFINED` defined?

Comment: @IcyFlame: You can take the `b` prefix off for compatibility with 2.5

Comment: @IcyFlame: You can leave the `.decode()` off the `return` or try my Unicode capable update.

Comment: @martineau, the official version is built with Visual Studio. These functions are prototyped in `<conio.h>`, and [PC/pycofig.h](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/bd8afb90ebf2/PC/pyconfig.h#l457) defines `HAVE_CONIO_H` for all but Windows CE. I also tested that it works in 3.3 on my Windows box (ssh'd in; I use Debian ;)

Comment: @IcyFlame: `getch` is a console IO function (conio); it won't work in IDLE and other GUI shells.

Comment: @IcyFlame: For a GUI answer, see the answer by [for i in range awesome](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15312255/205580). Or you could use `PyGame`, among other options.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about how to read input without input, you probably are looking for binding
This requires a Tkinter window, I believe.

```
lapEnded = bind_all("<KeyPress-l>", endLap)
stopRunning = bind_all("<KeyPress-s", noMoreRunning)
```

Then, you define the functions `endLap` and `noMoreRunning`, which do their functions.
Depending on your version of Tkinter and/or Python, `bind_all` may simply be `bind`.
Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use msvcrt library in IDLE. Try your code in Windows command line.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).