# Using msvcrt.getch()

Tags: python, python-3.x, getch

I am creating a guessing program that allow two player to compete where one input a number and the other guess the answer. However At first I used the input code for the user to enter a number but this displayed the user input which allow the second user to view entry.

Hovwever I tired using numberGuess = msvcrt.getch() as a result I got the outcome shown below. what should I do so that i can perform the same checks on numberGuess without getting an error? as well as the user entry is replace with "*"

My Code:

```
import msvcrt
from random import randint
import struct
def HumanAgainstHuman ():
    changemax = input("Would you like to change the maximum?")
    if changemax.lower() == "yes":
       maxNumber = int(input("Enter the new max:"))
    else:
       maxNumber = 9

    numberGuess = msvcrt.getch()
    nuberGuress= int(numberGuess)

    while numberGuess < 1 or numberGuess > maxNumber:
          numberGuess = input("Not a valid choice, please enter another number: \n").replace
          guess = 0
          numberGuesses = 0
    while guess != numberGuess and numberGuesses < 3:
          guess = int(input("Player Two have a guess: \n"))
          numberGuesses = numberGuesses + 1
    if guess == numberGuess:
        print("Player Two wins")
    else:
        print("Player One wins")

    PlayAgain()

 def choosingGame():

     Choice = int(input("Choose...\n 1 for Human Vs Human \n 2 for Human Vs AI \n 3 for AI Vs AI \n"))

     while Choice < 1 or Choice > 3:
           Choice = int(input("Try again...Choose...\n 1 for Human Vs Human \n 2 for Human Vs AI \n 3 for AI Vs AI \n"))

     if Choice == 1:
        HumanAgainstHuman()
     elif Choice == 2:
          HagainstAI()
    elif Choice == 3:
          AIagainstAI()

def PlayAgain():
     answer = int(input("Press 1 to play again or Press any other number to end"))
     if answer == 1:
            choosingGame()
    else:
         print("Goodbye!")
         try:
             input("Press enter to kill program")
         except SyntaxError:
           pass

 choosingGame()
```

Outcome when running the program

```
    Choose...
    1 for Human Vs Human 
    2 for Human Vs AI 
    3 for AI Vs AI 
    1
    Would you like to change the maximum?no
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:/Users/Sarah/Documents/testing.py", line 55, in <module>
           choosingGame()
       File "C:/Users/Sarah/Documents/testing.py", line 38, in choosingGame
           HumanAgainstHuman()
       File "C:/Users/Sarah/Documents/testing.py", line 14, in HumanAgainstHuman
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\xff'
```

Comment: I don't think you meant to have `nuberGuress` in there...

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? What key did you press to get the `ValueError`?

Comment: @martineau python 3.5

Comment: @PM2Ring do you mean instead of numberGuess = msvcrt.getch() I should type  msvcrt.getch() only  if I do so how can I check the user input against the other player.

Comment: PM2Ring means the `nuberGuress= int(numberGuess)`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem using Python 3.5.2.

Comment: To say it more plainly: `nuberGuress` looks like a typo, and you _really_ meant to type `numberGuess= int(numberGuess)`. martineau has run your code after fixing that typo and it appears to function perfectly on his machine. I can't test your code because I don't use Windows.

Comment: You could try using the `readch()` function in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311887/unbuffered-character-input-for-python-on-a-windows-machine) of mine.

Comment: @ PM 2Ring even after fixing the variable error still getting an error as folllow  Choose...
 1 for Human Vs Human 
 2 for Human Vs AI 
 3 for AI Vs AI 
1
Would you like to change the maximum?no
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sarah/Documents/testing.py", line 55, in <module>
    choosingGame()
  File "C:/Users/Sarah/Documents/testing.py", line 38, in choosingGame
    HumanAgainstHuman()
  File "C:/Users/Sarah/Documents/testing.py", line 14, in HumanAgainstHuman
    numberGuress= int(numberGuess)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\xff'
>>>

Comment: Sarah: How is that different from the traceback shown in your question. It's usually better to [edit] your question to add such information.

Comment: @martineau thanks for highlighting, I did not thought of that

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, I can't reproduce your problem with `getch()`. That said, below is an improved (but still imperfect) version of the `HumanAgainstHuman()` function that illustrates a way to use `getch()` that should guard against the type of problem you're encountering.

The function has another problem in that it attempts to reference the value of the variable `guess` before one has been assigned to it — however since I don't understand precisely what you were trying to do, that issue remains in the code to be solved...

```
def HumanAgainstHuman():
    changemax = input("Would you like to change the maximum?")
    if changemax.lower() == "yes":
        maxNumber = int(input("Enter the new max:"))
    else:
        maxNumber = 9

    numberGuess = msvcrt.getch()
    try:
        numberGuess = int(numberGuess)
    except ValueError:
        numberGuess = 0  # assign it some invalid number

    while numberGuess < 1 or numberGuess > maxNumber:
        numberGuess = input("Not a valid choice, please enter another number:\n")
        guess = 0
        numberGuesses = 0
    while guess != numberGuess and numberGuesses < 3:  ## different problem here!
        guess = int(input("Player Two have a guess:\n"))
        numberGuesses = numberGuesses + 1
    if guess == numberGuess:
        print("Player Two wins")
    else:
        print("Player One wins")

    PlayAgain()
```